# CELL (communication between SPEs)

Tags: c, spu

Working with CELL there are PPU and SPU.

My question is how do you communicate between SPE-s?

I know that a SPU program can access the mailbox of an other SPE through DMA functions (defined in spu_mfcio.h), if these are mapped in the local program state of the SPU.

However, I don't know how to do that, please help me.

I would add that I work in C language.